# How to select a jenkins agent for a build based on github branch?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Our project is written in java and deployed on to a Solaris environment in production. But , most of our test and dev machines are in Linux and so are our most Jenkins agents.

**I'm looking for a way to run the Jenkins build in a Solaris agent only when the branch is master/release_branch and choose a Linux agent when the branch is something else.**

Idea is to ensure we haven't introduced any compatibility issues in Solaris.
I'm looking for a declarative pipeline approach something like this, but will also select linux agent when condition is  not met.

```
stage('build') {
  steps {
    mvn clean 
  }

  when {
    branch comparator: 'EQUALS', pattern: 'master'
    beforeAgent true
  }

  agent { 
    label 'Solaris' 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `when` can do that. If you don't mind a bit of scripting you can do it like this

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            agent {
                label env.GIT_BRANCH == 'master' ? 'Solaris' : 'Linux'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'hostname'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you are storing the pipeline in git. I'm sure Bitbucket has a similar env variable.

Comment: I think this will work for me. I'm storing the pipeline file on git. Thank you